# Java code to ruby

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hmacsha1

I want to convert this to ruby syntax but i can not understand the method being used to encode in the following code.

```
String orderAmount = "250.00";
String mobile = " 7687675645";
String email = "a@abc.com"  ;
String data=mobile+email+orderAmount+"INR";
javax.crypto.Mac mac = javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(secret_key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1"));
byte[] hexBytes = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex().encode(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
String signature = new String(hexBytes, "UTF-8");
```

Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some test data for this, that can be shared? It would be great to have you input/output sample and keys to get this sample

Comment: "i can not understand the method being used to encode in the following code" – You don't *need* to understand the method in order to convert it to Ruby syntax. You would only need to understand it if you wanted to convert it to Ruby semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.html):

```
require 'openssl'

secret_key = 'place_your_secret_key_here'
orderAmount = '250.00'
mobile = ' 7687675645'
email = 'a@abc.com'
data = mobile + email + orderAmount + 'INR'

signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('SHA1', secret_key, data)
```

Comment: Thanks , had used the same thing.